# Programmatically Changing Order's Weight

Tags: magento2, product-weight

Our products have custom fields corresponding to weight. How could I add (and update) this weight for the order, so that shipping is calculated with this new weight*?

*Product weight value + custom field weight value.

To clarify my calculation, I've added a custom "weight" field to customizable options with the intention of adding the weight of these selections to the base product weight, so that it's a factor in shipping.

Comment: Which shipping method?

Comment: Any shipping method, actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also I didn't exactly understand what your shipping calculation is, I would suggest the following solution - if you need the calculated value for the weight everywhere in the store:

Create a plugin after the public method `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::getWeight()` and overwrite the return value (i.e. the original product weight value) with your calculation. In this way you have to add a single 1-2 lines method and the `di.xml`configuration and will get your custom weight everywhere you call `getWeight()` of the product.

If you need the original value of the weight in some places of your store and the calculated value only in the shipping calculation, please provide some more information about that code. There are many different possibilities where you can plugin and add your calculated value to the product object.

For setting the custom weight based on selected custom options you may plug in before `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item::setWeight`. The quote item model has the selected custom options and the products original weight, so you might calculate your custom weight there.

Comment: Just clarified my calculation/needs in my post. This is a great start, thank you! Do you think I could check if a Custom Option has been selected in the getWeight() method?

Comment: I updated my answer, please try that method for plugging in

Comment: Thanks @HelgeB -- I was actually trying to plug in there yesterday, wasn't able to see any results. I'm going to keep at it. Thank you!

Comment: Hey @HelgeB, I see setWeight within the setProduct function, so that the one I'd want to override?

Comment: not the `setProduct`, but the `setWeight` method. `beforeSetWeight` should be your plugin method, I've updated my answer. Before becouse you get the weight which should be set (i.e. the products weight) as parameter and you can add your custom value and return the result, which is passed to the `setWeight()` method of the quote model.

Comment: I am, as of now, trying to learn a lot about plugins. Right now, in my di.xml, I have the type name as "Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item". My plugin file has this in its class: public function beforeSetWeight(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $quoteItem) --- but would I be able to hook into SetWeight if it's not a public function in module-quote/Model/Quote/Item.php? Just confused about how that's work; trying to test it with a logger but failing to produce results so far. Thanks for your help!

Comment: setWeight() in quote item model is public. It' s a simple (implicit) setter for the corresponding field in the database table.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me, but that's what's confusing about it to me-- so I can use the plugin to hone in on any function used this model, not just the defined methods of that particular class? I've seen examples of plugins with respect to class methods, but setter/getter methods etc. Just confused about how to set this up, apologies.

Comment: Give it a try, if you won't have success with that I'll update my answer with some code tommorow

Comment: Hmm, I can get my plugin to work (logging a debug message) if I use beforeSetProduct, but not beforeSetWeight

Comment: Ok, then you can try also to add there your weight. Just manipulate the weight of the product object passed as input parameter as you need. It will be passed in the setProduct method to setWeight

Comment: Hey @HelgeB, if you're out there somewhere and feeling sagey: I was able to get all of this working, but the reset weight in the Quote Item model isn't being used for shipping calculations. Can you think of what I might be missing there? Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: (also, would you prefer I made that a distinct question?)

Comment: If the weight is saved correctly with the changed value in the quote_item and order_item table I would say we need to look at the calculation process of your shipping costs. Please open a new question since here is a lot of stuff in the comments and it won't get better with more :-). Please add also some details about your shipping calculation and it's dependency to weight. I'm not sure where that happens in Standard Magento

Comment: Hey @HelgeB , here's my new question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/265987/60595 Thank you!