# Set quote item product custom weight no holding through shipping

Tags: magento2, product, shipping, custom-options, product-weight

I am trying to set a custom product weight based on a set product custom option.
I've tried multiple things like a plugin, before/after events, actual events like `sales_quote_add_item` etc.

I am able to set the product weight during these processes, but once I get to calculating shipping it seems to load the original product weight, not the weight from the `quote_item` table.

At this point I've removed everything except the `sales_quote_add_item` code.
Any help is appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this answer it may help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/265987/overriding-quote-item-weight-programatically/266045#266045

Comment: I will give this a shot again. I believe I tried this and it did not work. I will report back.

Comment: Thank you that did seem to be the answer!